# Robust computation for the $2 \times 2$ matrix exponential formula

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

A formula for the $2 \times 2$ matrix exponential is given in Awad H. Al-Mohy and Nicholas J. Higham, (2009), "A New Scaling and Squaring Algorithm for the Matrix Exponential" for a matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{bmatrix}$ as

$$e^A = e^{(a+d) / 2}\begin{bmatrix}
cosh(\mu / 2) + \frac{1}{2}(a-d)sinch(\mu/2) & b \cdot sinch(\mu/2) \\
c \cdot sinch(\mu/2) & cosh(\mu / 2) + \frac{1}{2}(a-d)sinch(\mu/2)
\end{bmatrix}$$

where $\mu = \sqrt{(a-d)^2 + 4bc}$

My problem is that sometimes $\mu$ is too large, causing $\cosh$ to overflow. I have tried scaling the matrix by it's Frobenius norm, and using the fact that $e^A = (e^{A/||A||})^{||A||}$ to get the exponential for the original matrix. I am wondering if there is a better way for doing this without having to take the power of a matrix, or perhaps a smarter and numerically stable way of scaling $A$.

Comment: Does computing the eigendecomposition/jordan form $A = VJV^{-1}$ and then computing $e^A = Ve^J V^{-1}$ work, or does that also cause overflow issues?

Comment: https://www.cs.jhu.edu/~misha/ReadingSeminar/Papers/Moler03.pdf